# Entropy Departure - BWRS Equation of State

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, entropy, physical-chemistry, gas

Edit: This was not a homework problem. I simply pulled an example from a textbook to easily illustrate and convey the problem at hand.

I am seeking some assistance in evaluating the entropy change of a real gas using BWRS-EOS. I have successfully accomplished this using Peng-Robinsons which will be used as a point for comparison. Any feedback or suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Consider Example 8.8. Enthalpy and entropy from the Peng-Robinson equation - Introductory Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics by J. Richard Elliott.

As evaluated via BWRS-EOS for Propane -
Python script:  https://pastebin.com/80w9npaT

T1 = 378.15 K,   P1 = 500 kPaA,   Enthalpy Departure = -407.06 J/mol,   Entropy Departure = -52.43 J/mol,    Cp Ideal = 89.82 J/mol.K

T2 = 463.15 K,   P2 = 2500 kPaA, Enthalpy Departure = -1324.7 J/mol,   Entropy Departure = -67.12 J/mol,    Cp Ideal = 105.04 J/mol.K

**$\Delta H = \Delta H_{ideal} + \Delta H_{real} = C_p * (T2 - T1) + (\Delta H_{departure2} - \Delta H_{departure1})$**

enthalpy_delta = 0.5*(89.82+105.04)*(463.15-378.15) + (-1324.7-(-407.06)) = 7363.91 J/mol  **CORRECT**

**$\Delta S = \Delta S_{ideal} + \Delta S_{real} = C_p * ln(\frac{T2}{T1})-R*ln(\frac{P2}{P1}) + (\Delta S_{departure2} - \Delta S_{departure1})$**

entropy_delta = 0.5*(89.82+105.04)*ln(463.15/378.15) - 8.31447 * ln(2500/500) + (-67.12-(-52.43)) = -8.32 J/mol.K. **INCORRECT**

The results for enthalpy are correct, however, entropy is horribly incorrect. I strongly believe this is due to the entropy departure values which differ from what I calculate via Peng-Robinson by over 1000%. As summarised in the comparison between PR-EOS and BWRS-EOS below, the entropy departure as calculated by BWRS is an order of magnitude larger than PR-EOS.

[image]

Any advice would be highly appreciated, I've been struggling for a while and cannot get this to work.

Entropy departure per K.E Starling:

[image]

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: What do you get if you omit the first term on the right hand side of the departure equation?

Comment: Significantly closer: Entropy Delta = 5.595 J/mol.K. state1 Entropy Departure = -0.438, state2 Departure = -1.22. Is this technically correct? I'll check this against some other examples and compare the results

Comment: does not seem to produce correct results for other cases I have tried :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BWRS approach is based on molar volume = 1/rho.  As such, to apply the Starling entropy departure equation, you start with $C_v^{IG}\ln{(T2/T1)}$ and apply the Starling entropy departure corrections to this.

Alternately, you can start with the full ideal gas relationship $C_v^{IG}\ln{(T_2/T_1)}-R\ln{(\rho_2/\rho_1)}$ and then apply the Starling entropy departure equation, with the first term omitted because it represents the ideal gas contribution of molar volume.

Comment: THANK YOU. I'm now calculating dS = 5.07J/mol via BWRS which is extremely close to example problem. Thank you so much Chett, once again you have delivered.

Comment: I am getting excellent results now. THANK YOU.

Comment: Whoops just realised I was using Cp Ideal. Not Cv Ideal as you suggested. Cv does not work. Cp works. Thoughts?

Comment: What value did you get for $\int_{T_1}^{T_2}{\frac{C_vdT}{T}}$?  I got roughly 18.0 J/mole.K

Comment: What were the values of rho1 and rho2

Comment: This site gives a value of 4.93 J/mole.K for $\Delta S$:  http://www.ethermo.us/Show71Vatemp!463.15!1~press!2500!1.htm

Comment: STATE 1:
Z: 0.9617, Molar Volume: 6047.7cm3/mol, Enthalpy Departure: -407.1J/mol, Entropy Departure: -52.4J/mol, CpID: 89.8J/mol.K, CvID: 81.5 J/mol.K.

Comment: STATE2: Z: 0.9028,
Molar Volume: 1390.6cm3/mol, Enthalpy Departure: -1234.7J/mol, Entropy Departure: -67.1J/mol, CpID: 105.0J/mol.K, CvID: 97.7J/mol.K.

Comment: CvID * ln(T2/T1) = (97.7+81.5)/2*ln(463.15/378.15) = 18.16 J/mol.K
Very close to your 18.0 K/mol.K

Comment: Calculating dS with CpID:
dS = (89.8+105.0)/2*ln(463.15/378.15)+(-67.1-(-52.4)) = 5.05 J/mol.K

Comment: Calculating dS with CvID:
(81.5+97.7)/2*ln(463.15/378.15)+(-67.1-(-52.4)) = 3.47 J/mol.K

Comment: As you can see CpID must be used. Applying CvID as you originally suggested appears to produce an incorrect result.

Comment: I went through the derivation again, and determined that you are correct about using Cp rather than Cv.  The term $-R\ln{(\rho RT)}$ in the entropy departure expression does two things.  First, it adds $-R\ln{(T_2/T_1)}$, which converts the Cp tern to a Cv term.  Secondly, it contributes $-R\ln{(\rho_2/\rho_1)}=+R\ln{(v_2/v_1)}$ to account for the contribution of the ideal gas specific volume term to the ideal gas entropy change.

Comment: Fascinating ! Thank you for your insight and feedback. Where would be the best place to learn these derivations? Can you recommend any textbooks or journal articles. Thank you

Comment: The how-to is in Smith and Van Ness, Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out, cheers

Comment: Trying to now evaluate the partial derivatives (dV/dT)P and (dV/dP)T for BWRS which are required to calculate volume expansivity and isothermal compressibility. Surly these kind of derivations have been done before and are readily available on the internet.

Comment: I don't know where to find them on the internet, but submit these straightforward mathematical questions on PhysicsForums.com, and I'll be pleased to provide the desired derivations.

Comment: Thanks I have made a new submission. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found another resource suggesting the same derivation for entropy departure. Again produces unsatisfactory results. Could there be a units issue?

[image]